# Something went wrong, post is highlighted with a gray background

Tags: discussion, keyboard-shortcuts

If I press <kbd>c</kbd> in a page (for both a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322593/overflow-exception-double-into-int) and an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322593/overflow-exception-double-into-int/38322750#38322750)) it will get highlighted with a gray background and the cursor will be placed inside the comment box. It won't change the background even after I submit the comment. Here I have an screenshot, what is wrong with this? Is this a bug or browser issue? I'm using Chrome. Here (on Meta) pressing <kbd>c</kbd> won't trigger anything but it *is* happening in Stack Overflow.

**Updates**

A similar thing will happen when I press <kbd>m</kbd> or <kbd>u</kbd>. But this time the comment box is not showing. <kbd>e</kbd> will open the post in Edit mode but the background color remains the same even after save the edit. Similarly <kbd>r</kbd> will open the Achievements and <kbd>i</kbd> will open the Inbox etc. For the inbox and achievements, an additional box opens as shown in the image below:
[image: Inbox and Achievements]
[image: Highlighted post]

Answer (score 2):

Those (<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>) are [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one). You need to enable this in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/5195227) *for every site*; if you enable it on the 'main' Stack Overflow, it isn't automatically enabled for Meta Stack Overflow.

The grey box is to indicate clearly which post you are commenting (i.e. on the question, not on the answer). The extra box for the Inbox and Achievements is to navigate further, i.e. to jump to the seventh item in the Inbox, just press <kbd>7</kbd>. It is easier to search for the text in the black box than to count the number of items from the top.

Comment: well, I have few more updates in the question. Could you please take a look

Comment: Yes, you are correct, by un-checking the checkbox it stops triggering the events. I'm expecting your comments on the extra box on Achievements and Inbox

Answer (score 0):

The full list of keyboard shortcuts that select a post are:

| Key | function |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>J</kbd> | Select next post going down the page |
| <kbd>K</kbd> | Select previous post going up the page |
| <kbd>U</kbd> | Select first/topmost post on the page. For a Q&A that would be the question |
| <kbd>V</kbd> | (Auto-selects a post) **V**ote. Opens a submenu, follow the keystroke with <kbd>U</kbd> for Vote Up or <kbd>V</kbd> -> <kbd>D</kbd> for Vote Down |
| <kbd>E</kbd> | (Auto-selects a post) **E**dit. If you have full edit privileges, opens the in-place editor and highlights the post. For suggested edits it sends you to the dedicated editing page |
| <kbd>T</kbd> | (Auto-selects a post) Re**t**ag. [Requires 10k reputation for access to the inline tag editor.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Always auto-selects the question in a Q&A, regardless of where in the page you are |
| <kbd>C</kbd> | (Auto-selects a post) Add/Show **c**omments. Expands any collapsed comments, opens the textbox to add a comment. |
| <kbd>L</kbd> | (Auto-selects a post) **L**ink. Opens the "Share" link under the post. |
| <kbd>M</kbd> | (Auto-selects a post) **M**oderate. Opens a submenu, follow the keystroke with <kbd>F</kbd> - Flag, <kbd>C</kbd> - Close vote, <kbd>D</kbd> - Delete/Undelete vote, <kbd>I</kbd> - Other Issues (opens another submenu with <kbd>T</kbd> - Timeline) |